# How to get float value with two decimal values in C language?

Tags: c

i like to get float value with first two decimal value in C language.

my input is

```
Float f;
f=2.3678;
```

i like to get output like this

```
2.36
```

Comment: If you don't want to round, why is this tagged `round`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the `math.h` header file and do this:

```
float f;
f = 2.3678;
f = floor(f * 100) / 100;
// f = 2.36
```

Comment: Technically, that number isn't 2.36, it's 2.359999999999999875655021241982467472553253173828125. Truth.

Comment: @Chris: There's not much I can do about that :)

Comment: Right. My point is that the OP's question cannot be answered with floating-point numbers.

Comment: Who turned on your -pedantic option?  :)  Edit: well, it isn't as funny now that you added your second comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%.2f", 2.3678);   /* prints 2.37 */
```

Comment: I dont need round off my Value i have to ignore all other value after 2 decimal places

Comment: @ratty: You want to round down? Then use minitech's approach: `printf("%.2f", floor(2.3678 * 100) / 100)`.

Comment: That's dangerous. Look what happens if you use `floor(2.36 * 100) / 100`... (per your own comments)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f=f*100;
f=(int)f;
f=f/100;
```